# Retaining the name of the transferred file

Tags: java, sockets, java-io, serversocket

I am using normal Java Socket Programming to successfully transfer a known file. This is my code snippet:

```
Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.1.3", 6789);
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[9999];
InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("filename.txt");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
bos.close();
sock.close();
```

However in this code I have to explicitly name the receiving file as `filename.txt`, I want to retain the name of the file that is getting transferred. One way to do is to explicitly transfer the name of the file and then transfer the file (I think it is correct) OR is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The socket has no filename. You read bytes from the socket as they come, they could be anything.

Comment: I agree to that, but is there any way to retain the filename from which I am transferring the bytes?

Answer (score 1):

you should add the name of the file in the stream and use a separator to mark it from the contents

If you can't change the stream, worst case is to use another connection only to send the name, close it, and then read the contents from another stream

Answer (score 1):

You are transferring a stream of bytes that pertain to a file, whose file name at the source is not relevant at the destination in order to successfully transfer the file bytes. If you care about the name of the file given at the source, send that file name separately to the destination.